# How we see the total content in EditText in android

Tags: android

Thank u But after the Edit Text I use the Icons also .So,when i give Wrap_content for that Edittext The icons are displayed only half   ,In below my code is there see that one once

```
<TableRow 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextViewEmail"
    android:text="Email" 
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:paddingRight="4dip" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
    android:layout_gravity="right|center" /> 
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/EditTextEmail"    
    android:editable="false" 
    android:clickable="false" 
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:singleLine="true" android:layout_width="150sp"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a TextView instead, and give

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Or for your EditText you use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:editable="false"
```